# ASP.NET Web Api Plugin Architecture

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am looking to find a method of implementing a plugin architecture for web api.
I found half of my question here:

[ASP.NET Web.Api plugin architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673115/asp-net-web-api-plugin-architecture)

Though the missing part of my question is this

I understand how routing would work with the example, what if I wanted to assign a 
RoutePrefix attribute for the controllers in the plugin folders based on their folder location?

Perhaps within the plugins folder we had sub folders, each containing a plugin.
Plugins\Standard\Item1
Plugins\Standard\Item2
Plugins\Vendors\Vendor1\Item1

For the above folder structure, how could we assign the RoutePrefix with your loading code?
so regardless of what the developer named the controllers, we would override them.

["api/plugins/standard/item1"]

["api/plugins/standard/item2"]

["api/plugins/vendors/vendor1/item1"]

This would allow the api developer / owner to remain in control of routing, when the plugins come from other sources other than their own.

Regards

Louis

Comment: Did you get this to work ? Web API using Plugin architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

C# attributes can not be created at runtime. You have to specify a string at compile time, so it has to be fairly static.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. That is quite a let down. Can you perhaps think of some other way, where this could be dynamic? With the solution provided by the previous person has some inherent issues, what if two companies or more made plugins and their controllers are called AcmeController, and I think that this is very likely to occur.

Comment: Not sure I know of a great solution. However, maybe you can create controllers with your own naming convention that inherits the controllers uploaded by the clients?